# Set-SBCertificate not finding a valid certificate

Tags: powershell, servicebus

I am attempting to apply pre-generated (from Active Directory CA) certificates to our On-Premise service bus environment via powershell. Below are the scripts I am executing:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root | ?{$_.FriendlyName -eq '[CERTS FRIENDLY NAME]'}

Set-SBCertificate -EncryptionCertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint -FarmCertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint`
```

Below is the error that i am getting:

> Set-SBCertificate : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'EncryptionCertificateThumbprint'. Valid certificate with
>   thumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx not found
>   At line:1 char:52
>   + Set-SBCertificate -EncryptionCertificateThumbprint $encryptCert.Thumbprint -Farm ...
>   +                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-SBCertificate], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.SetSBFarmCertificate

List of the things I have done to troubleshoot this:

1. Verified that the $cert actually contains a cert.
2. Verified that the cert actually is installed on the server by going to mmc.exe and looking into the "Certificates (Local Computer)/Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates".
3. Attempted to use 2 difference certs for Farm and Encryption.

Does anyone have any ideas on this issue? Or possibly know where the powershell module is attempting to look for the certificates at? Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: How does your FQDN look like? See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sguyge/archive/2013/04/29/running-service-bus-server-on-a-legacy-domain-without-a-fully-qualified-domain-name.aspx)...

Comment: The details "Subject:CN" is equivalent to the result of this:

[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(($env:computerName))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this command to find the certificates we had to add them to  Certificates (Local Computer) under both "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"  and "Personal."

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the entire certificate was deleted (dont know how).
I open the Regedit, and remove the entire ServiceBus from HKey_current_User and Hkey_Local_Machine and inside Microsoft deleted the entire Service Bus folder.

Than from Control Panel Add Remove program unstall the Service Bus.

Reinstall the Service Bus.